# Error loading Teradata ODBC driver in docker for a python project

Tags: python, docker, odbc, teradata, alpine-linux

I am trying to connect to Teradata Database using python teradata module. But I am getting below exception when I run my application in docker ::

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py", line 183, in connect
    **args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 421, in __init__
    init(odbcLibPath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 366, in init
    initOdbcLibrary(odbcLibPath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 319, in initOdbcLibrary
    odbc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(odbcLibPath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: Error relocating /opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/libodbc.so: _toupper: symbol not found
```

I have the same code running in my windows machine but the issue is when I run same code in Docker. In my windows machine I have the Teradata ODBC 16.20 installed but maybe I'm missing something when I try to do same in docker, since I'm new to docker.

**Docker File ::**

```
FROM python:alpine3.7

ADD test.py /
USER root
ADD tdodbc1620__linux_indep.16.20.00.54-1.tar.gz /tmp/
RUN apk add rpm
RUN rpm -ivh /tmp/tdodbc1620/tdodbc1620-16.20.00.54-1.noarch.rpm --prefix=/opt/ --nodeps    
RUN cp /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini
RUN cp /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbcinst.ini ~/.odbcinst.ini    
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install teradata        
ENV ODBCHOME=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/ ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbc.ini ODBCINST=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbcinst.ini
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64    
RUN chown -R root /opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/*.so    
CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

**Python Code ::**

```
import teradata

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method='odbc', system='xyz.com', username='xyz', password='xyz', AUTHENTICATION='LDAP')

with session as connect :
    for row in connect.execute("`select top 5 * from EMPLOYEE;`"):
        print(row)
```

Expected Result :: Print Top 5 rows from EMPLOYEE table.

**Latest Copy of Docker File using RHEL OS** :

```
FROM quay.********/rhel:latest

ADD test.py /
USER root
RUN yum --nogpgcheck -y install unzip sudo vim wget which tar gzip graphviz python-setuptools python-setuptools-devel shadow-utils git net-tools libXtst.x86_64 python-pip 
RUN yum -y install libgcc_s.so.1
RUN yum -y install libstdc++.so.6

ADD tdodbc1620__linux_indep.16.20.00.54-1.tar.gz ./

RUN cd /tdodbc1620/ && \ 
    ./setup_wrapper.sh -s -r tdodbc1620-16.20.00.54-1.noarch.rpm

RUN  pip install teradata

ENV ODBCHOME=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64 
ENV ODBCINI=$ODBCHOME/odbc.ini 
ENV ODBCINST=$ODBCHOME/odbcinst.ini
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ODBCHOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that OS fails to resolve symbol `_toupper` when loading binary library of the ODBC driver. Standard C functions like `toupper`, `snprintf`, etc. are provided by C runtime library.

In order to minimize image size [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/about/) is built on musl implementation of standard C runtime. Most of the other Linux distributions use GNU C library (glibc). [Musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html) is designed to be lightweight and fast implementation conforming to ISO C and POSIX standards, so most applications require no, or minimal source code changes to be compiled with musl. However ABI (application binary interface) compatibility is quite limited, therefore many binaries compiled with glibc will fail to run with musl.

If recompiling ODBC driver from source code is not an option, the easiest approach would be to switch from Alpine to a base image that has glibc runtime, same as required by the ODBC driver binary.

Comment: I have tried doing **apk upgrade musl**  but still same issue persists  " OSError: Error relocating **/opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/libodbc.so** : _toupper: symbol not found "

Comment: Try debian base image, i.e. replace `python:alpine3.7` with `python:3.7`
You may need to download terradata ODBC driver for ubuntu instead of generic linux

Comment: Thanks @JKW, I was able to resolve above issue by using rhel  **OS** . But still not sure what wen wrong with Alpine OS. I have added my latest Dcoker file using which I was able to query teradata.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more details on the root cause. Hope this helps.